# When we deploy our Django app to Heroku it says "changes that are not yet reflected in a migration," but also says it has no migrations to make

Tags: django, heroku

My local repo is up-to-date with my Heroku repo.

When I run `makemigrations` or `migrate` locally, it says there are no changes.

When I run `makemigrations` on Heroku, it does these exact same changes every time, no matter how many times I run it:

```
python manage.py makemigrations users kits email
Migrations for 'kits':
  apps/kits/migrations/0002_auto_20221209_1204.py
    - Change Meta options on historicalkit
    - Alter field history_date on historicalkit
Migrations for 'users':
  apps/users/migrations/0002_auto_20221209_1204.py
    - Change Meta options on historicaluser
    - Alter field history_date on historicaluser
```

...but then if I run `migrate` on Heroku, it says there is nothing to migrate, AND that there are un-made migrations:

```
python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, email, kits, sessions, users
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models in app(s): 'kits', 'users' have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

This is causing our whole web app to go down. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

> When I run `makemigrations` on Heroku, it does these exact same changes every time, no matter how many times I run it

That makes sense.

When you `heroku run` something, Heroku spins up a [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos) in which to run the command. That dyno has its own ephemeral filesystem that isn't shared with other dynos.

So, every time you run that command it generates new migration files, saving them locally, and then immediately throws them away when the dyno spins down. Running it again gives you a fresh one-off dyno with a fresh filesystem.

Don't ever run `makemigrations` on Heroku. You should only do that locally.

> When I run `makemigrations` or `migrate` locally, it says there are no changes

You probably have up to date migration files (so there are none to generate) that aren't committed (so Heroku can't see them), or you're deploying from a branch where those files aren't committed.

Make sure the migration files are properly committed locally, then redeploy.